# How can I get updated value from ng-model in my controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to get the updated value from my view like this:

```html
<label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Palabra</span>
          <input style="font-size: 18px !important; text-align: right !important; font-weight: bold !important;" type="text" ng-model="addWordContent" placeholder="pa-la-bra">
        </label
```

I initialize the value of $scope.addWordContent in NULL:

```js
$scope.getEditPalabraRow = function($stateParams) {
    Words.getEditSimple($stateParams.palabraId).then(function(single){
      $scope.editWordRow = single;
      $scope.addWordContent = null;
      /*$scope.nodiacriso = Utilities.removeAccents($scope.editWordRow.sound_title);
      $scope.mintitle =  $filter('lowercase')($scope.nodiacriso);
      $scope.nodiacri = Utilities.removeAccents($scope.editWordRow.title);*/
      $scope.getEditLetter($scope.editWordRow);
      
          
    });
```

So I need to use the updated ng-model value when the user types a new word in the html `<input>`, then save it in my database, I am trying this in my controller:

```js
Words.addWord($scope.addWordContent, $scope.imgURI,  src, $scope.letter.letter_id, title);
```

Words is a service.

When I try to save the word the value still in NULL, never changes when the user fill the input text field. Regards!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article about scopes in angularjs wiki - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

I think this may be your case:

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't
>   even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding
>   (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string,
>   boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It
>   doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens
>   is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the
>   parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is
>   doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New
>   AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch,
>   ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the problem
>   often shows up when these directives are involved.

Comment: Thank you very much.... that works just pretty fine... this section  was the key: `Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use 
<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1"> rather than 
<input type="text" ng-model="prop1">. ` Regards

Comment: You should take a look at "controllerAs" syntax. This will help you to prevent such problems in future. This is also considered a best practice.

Comment: I´m using stateprovider so i call my controllers from a state, thank you.